# Date information disappears when save to CSV

Tags: r, date, csv, quantmod

I am trying to pull some data in from the internet and then export it to a CSV file, but I am loosing my date information in the  CSV file. I can't figure out why. I'm new to R so please keep responses simple. Here is my code:

```
Library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY", from = "2012-01-01", to = "2012-12-31")
write.csv(SPY, "C:/SPY.csv")
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8979241/841830

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as SPY is a xts/zoo object this will do the trick:

replace:

```
write.csv(SPY, "C:/SPY.csv")
```

with

```
write.zoo(SPY,"C:/SPY.csv",index.name="Date",sep=",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
write.csv(SPY, file= "SPY.csv", row.names = index(SPY))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the date information is being lost? If you are using MS-Excel to open the .CSV, it may be that Excel is munging your data.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely not there. It also does not have a column heading in the dataset in the R environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `str(SPY)` you get to see the inner structure of your xts object. The dates are in the index, not in the main data.

I use these three lines to save an xts object as a csv file:

```
#Convert to a data frame so it can be written to disk
d=as.data.frame(SPY)
d=cbind(datestamp=rownames(d),d)
write.csv(d,file="SPY.csv",row.names=F)
```

Comment: I thought there was a reason I used this idiom, instead of `write.zoo` but a hunt through both my code and StackOverflow reveals nothing. I'll leave this answer here as an alternative, but I think hvollmeier's answer is better.